# Histogram with timedifference on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRq0l.png)I am trying to plot a histogram with time difference calculated in seconds using `difftime()` function on x axis .
Below is how my histogram looks like [image]

```
ggplot(Q1_21_to_Q1_22, aes(x=timedif,color = member_casual)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="white",binwidth = 1000)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30000, by = 500))
```

Can anyone help me understand the problem and help with solution?

Comment: Please post sample data, preferably the result of `dput( YOUR DATA)`, and your expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is an issue with your x-axis. Try again without scale_x_continuous(). I can produce a similar plot to yours when I specify breaks with a max that is too small and bar width that's too narrow:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Q1_21_to_Q1_22, aes(x = timedif,color = member_casual)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "white", binwidth = 1000) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20000, by = 10000))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(Q1_21_to_Q1_22, aes(x = timedif,color = member_casual)) + 
  geom_histogram(fill = "white", binwidth = 100000)
```

[image]
data:

```
Q1_21_to_Q1_22 <- data.frame(
  t1 = sample(seq(as.Date('2022/01/01'), as.Date('2022/01/05'), by="day"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  t2 = sample(seq(as.Date('2022/01/05'), as.Date('2022/01/10'), by="day"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  member_casual = sample(c("casual", "member"), 1000, replace = TRUE))

Q1_21_to_Q1_22$timedif <- difftime(Q1_21_to_Q1_22$t2, Q1_21_to_Q1_22$t1, units = "sec")
```

Comment: If i dont specify scale_x_continious it says "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type difftime. Defaulting to continuous."
Also i have added an image of my sample data above.
Thanks

Comment: Using `...aes(x = as.numeric(timedif))...` would remove the warning. But the solution to your question is probably to simply to define your breaks differently in `scale_x_continuous()` and maybe make your binwidth larger.  My hunch is that you have large values in `timedif` that are much larger than your largest break value. I can't say for sure because you've only shared a small amount of data and in image form (sharing the results of dput as a code chunk makes these data usable).